# XSL selector where attribute can be upper or lowercase

Tags: xml, xslt

What is the XSL selector for a node value where an attribute can be upper or lower-case (or a combination)?  Here is an example (I've stripped off much of the XML that isn't relevant).  The first has an attribute of "NetworkID".  The latter is "networkid".  I need to get the value of the "Identity" node.

Attribute is "NetworkID".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cXML payloadID="1541780158582-6094783182107158181@216.109.111.67" timestamp="2018-11-09T08:15:58-08:00">
    <Header>
        <To>
            <Credential domain="networkid">
                <Identity>AN01000000000-T</Identity>
            </Credential>
        </To>
    </Header>
</cXML>
```

Attribute is "networkid".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cXML payloadID="1541780158582-6094783182107158181@216.109.111.67" timestamp="2018-11-09T08:15:58-08:00">
    <Header>
        <To>
            <Credential domain="NetworkID">
                <Identity>AN01000000000-T</Identity>
            </Credential>
        </To>
    </Header>
</cXML>
```

Is there a way to do this so that it ignores case?

`<xsl:value-of select="Header/To/Credential[@domain='networkid']/Identity"/>`

In my application, the above works in one case.  I am forced to change it manually to get it to work in the other (but it breaks the prior).

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0?

Comment: What would the 2.0 code be?  I'm not sure to be honest.  I've asked the vendor that question.

Comment: XSLT 2.0 has functions to convert a string to upper/lower case. The question is whether your XSLT processor supports XSLT 2.0. If you're not sure, find out - see here how: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244370/how-can-i-check-which-xslt-processor-is-being-used-in-solr/25245033?s=1|26.6139#25245033

Comment: I'm being told that it does support 2.0.  Do you know the selector code/syntax to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use XSLT 2.0, then replace your:

```
<xsl:value-of select="Header/To/Credential[@domain='networkid']/Identity"/>
```

with:

```
<xsl:value-of select="Header/To/Credential[lower-case(@domain)='networkid']/Identity"/>
```

---

In XSLT 1.0, define:

```
<xsl:variable name="upper-case" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
<xsl:variable name="lower-case" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
```

then use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="Header/To/Credential[translate(@domain, $upper-case, $lower-case)='networkid']/Identity"/>
```

Comment: It appears we are not able to use version 2 (our vendor appears to have been wrong).  How would you do this with 1.0?