# Apply templates to words and characters in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, text, format

I have XML files with text and I want to format certain words and characters. These could be within several elements, such as *l*, *add* and others. So I want to look up for characters like letter *e* or symbols and change its format. I want to exclude from my search text within *abbr* element.
Thanks.

**EDIT: I'm using XSLT 1.0 and I can't upgrade it.**

Take this text as an example:

```
<l n="1" type="latin">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <add type="con" xml:id="add2">consectetur</add> adipiscing elit, <abbr>se</abbr>d do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</l>
```

Desired output:

> Lor**e**m ipsum dolor sit am**e**t,cons**e**ct**e**tur
> adipiscing **e**lit, sed do **e**iusmod t**e**mpor
> incididunt ut labor**e** **e**t dolor**e** magna aliqua

XML Header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding ="UTF-8" standalone ="no" ?>
```

XSLT Header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs tei"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
```

Comment: You might want to check whether you can't use an XSLT 2 or 3 processor like Saxon (there is a Java version, a .NET version, a C/C++ version with PHP and Python bindings and there is Saxon JS 2 for browsers and for Node.js) or Altova or XmlPrime to make use of `xsl:analyze-string`.

Comment: In XSLT 1.0 you need to use a recursive named template to replace a search-string with markup - see an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46007915/3016153.

Comment: thank you! i'll try it

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using XSLT 3 and the `analyze-string` function:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Example</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[not(self::abbr)]/text()">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="analyze-string(., 'e+')" mode="wrap"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*:match" mode="wrap">
    <b>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </b>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks! But It doesn't work to me de to syntax erros. They seem to be in 'expand-text="yes"', 'xsl:output' and 'xsl:mode'

Comment: It ist XSLT 3 code so you need to use an XSLT 3 processor like Saxon 9.8 or newer, Saxon JS 2 or to Altova to run it.

Comment: Oh, okay!! sorry. Thank you!
Do you know methods using xslt 1.0?

Comment: XSLT 1.0 text processing is limited to functions like substring-after, substring-before, and contains, so it tends to be pretty difficult (and requires a lot of recursive code) to do anything at all complex.

Comment: Ok! Thank you so much!